# How to use result of called 'then' for next 'then'?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to return what I get after an async call.

So

```
app.get("/books", async (req, res) => {
    let books = await getBooks()
        .then(json => {
            res.status(200).send({"books": json});
        }); 
});
```

Should wait on rendering the result until the called `getBooks` is done.

```
export async function getBooks() {
    console.log("Getting books from cloud");
    Book.findAll({
        // ...

    }).then(books => {
        console.log("Got books");
        return JSON.stringify(books, null, 4);
    });
}
```

But right now the response gets rendered without actually waiting for the result.

Comment: Check this: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call It's probably gonna help you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use promises.  You can just use `await` and then use the result of that.

```
 app.get("/books", async (req, res) => {
   const books = await getBooks();
   res.status(200).send({ books });
 });
```

I'd highly suggest taking it a step further and using try/catch to handle failure cases

```
 app.get("/books", async (req, res) => {
   try {
     const books = await getBooks();
     res.status(200).send({ books });
   } catch (error) {
     // massage this to send the correct status code and body
     res.status(400).send( { error });
   }
 });
```

Comment: Correct and my answer was somewhat misleading.  I know async/await uses promises under the hood but I didn't want to get into that deep of a conversation for this answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use await in second method too:

```
export async function getBooks() {
console.log("Getting books from cloud");
var books = await Book.findAll({
    // ...

})
 if(books){
     console.log("Got books");
    return JSON.stringify(books, null, 4);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return your promise, and since you're just returning a promise you don't need `async`;.

```
app.get("/books", async (req, res) => {
    let json = await getBooks()
    res.status(200).send({"books": json});
});

export function getBooks() {
    console.log("Getting books from cloud");
    return Book.findAll({
        // ...

    }).then(books => {
        console.log("Got books");
        return JSON.stringify(books, null, 4);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/books", async (req, res) => {
    let books = await getBooks();
    res.status(200).send({"books": books});
})
```